# Wait until IE loads every tab vbscript

Tags: c#, vba, internet-explorer, vbscript

I've been trying to make a vbscript that waits until every tab I open with Internet Explorer has loaded. However, for some reason, it only waits until the last webpage I open finishes loading.
Here is my code:

```
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
WebSite = "https://www.google.com"
with objExplorer
.Navigate2 WebSite
.AddressBar = 1
.Visible = 1
.ToolBar = 1
.StatusBar = 1
end with


WebSite = "http://www.intel.com"
with objExplorer
.Navigate2 WebSite, &h800
.AddressBar = 1
.Visible = 1
.ToolBar = 1
.StatusBar = 1
end with


WebSite = "http://www.theverge.com"
with objExplorer
.Navigate2 WebSite, &h800
.AddressBar = 1
.Visible = 1
.ToolBar = 1
.StatusBar = 1
end with

Do While objExplorer.ReadyState <> 4 Or objExplorer.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 10
Loop

Do While objExplorer.Document.ReadyState <> "complete"
    WScript.Sleep 10
Loop
```

I load about 7 webpages, each in different tabs.
As a bonus, is it possible to do this on C# instead?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't loop through each tab and get the `ReadyState`?  As I'm reading your code, the `objExplorer` object is just for the current tab.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro Is it possible to have instead different objects for each tab and perform the "is it busy" check asynchronously?

Comment: That would be perfectly valid.

Comment: Apparently, vbscript can't run processes on multiple threads. My solution (which still doesn't answer the question) was to have a different object for each different IE window, instead of tabs, and then ask if each one was done loading to proceed to the next one.